# How to differentiate $y=\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to solve this problem but I think I'm missing something.

Here's what I've done so far:

$$g(x) = \frac{1+x}{1-x}$$

$$u = 1+x$$
$$u' = 1$$

$$v = 1-x$$
$$v' = -1$$

$$g'(x) = \frac{(1-x) -(-1)(1+x)}{(1-x)^2}$$
$$g'(x) = \frac{1-x+1+x}{(1-x)^2}$$
$$g'(x) = \frac{2}{(1-x)^2}$$

$$y' = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1+x}{1-x})^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\frac{2}{(1-x)^2})
$$

Comment: why not split it into $1/(1-x)$ and $x/(1-x)$?

Comment: You wanted to differentiate $ \sqrt{ g(x)}$, but not  $g(x)$ ! So proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another idea:

$$\frac{1+x}{1-x}=\frac2{1-x}-1\implies \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)'=\frac2{(1-x)^2}\implies$$

$$\left(\sqrt\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)'=\sqrt\frac{1-x}{1+x}\cdot\frac1{(1-x)^2}$$

Added on request:

$$\sqrt\frac{1-x}{1+x}\cdot\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\frac1{\sqrt{1+x}}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{1-x}\cdot(1-x)}=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}(1-x)}$$

Comment: The answer for this problem is $\frac{1}{(1-x)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. How would you solve the last part to make it like the correct answer?

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira It's just simple algebra: my answer's identical to yours. Look at the added stuff in myanswer.

Answer (score 8):

Make your life simpler by logging: 
$$
L f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \log (1+x) - \frac{1}{2} \log (1-x)
$$
Now differentiate this and multply by $f(x)$.

Comment: Why do I have to use log to solve this problem?

Comment: you don't 'have to', there are 6 solutions here and all of them are correct; logging makes your life easier because it simplifies the routine greatly.

Comment: Ok. I've asked the wrong question. I don't understand how you transformed the initial expression into the one with log.

Comment: Log function has 2 main properties (which?), use them to get this expression.

Answer (score 1):

let

$x=\cos u$
$$y=\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos u}{1-\cos u}}=\cot(\frac{u}{2})$$
$$y'=\frac{-1}{2}\csc^2(u/2)$$

then 
$u=\arccos x$

Answer (score 0):

Write:

$$ y^2 = \frac{ 1 + x}{1 -x } \iff y^2 = 1 + \frac{2x}{1-x}$$ 
so taking derivative with repect to $x$ gives

$$ 2y y' = \frac{2(1-x) + 2x}{(1-x)^2} =\frac{2}{(1-x)^2} $$

so

$$ y' = \sqrt{ \frac{1-x}{1+x} } (1-x)^2$$

Comment: In your last expression I think that squared term must be in the denominator

Answer (score 0):

$$ y^2=\frac{1+x}{1-x}=\frac2{1-x}-1\implies Derivative =\frac2{(1-x)^2} $$

$$ 2 y y ^{'} = RHS $$

$$y'=\sqrt\frac{1-x}{1+x}\cdot\frac1{(1-x)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
y' = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)
$$
Chain rule through the square root:
$$
y' = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)
$$
Quotient rule on what's left
$$
y' = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\left(\frac{1-x-(1+x)(-1)}{(1-x)^2}\right)
$$
Simplify
$$
y' = \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
$$